# PHP:- In multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I use two array with multidimensional.

I want to need remove same value with all remove element, but without use any function.

See below my code for multidimensional array.

```
<?php 

$a=array("0" => "test_3","1" => "test_4");

$b=array('test'=>array("label"=>"TEST","value"=>array(
                            "0"=>array("value"=>"test_1","label"=>"[test] Services_1"),
                            "1"=>array("value"=>"test_2","label"=>"[test] Services_2"),
                            "2"=>array("value"=>"test_3","label"=>"[test] Services_3"),
                            "3"=>array("value"=>"test_4","label"=>"[test] Services_4"),
                        )
                      ),
         'test1'=>array("label"=>"TEST","value"=>array(
                            "0"=>array("value"=>"test_11","label"=>"[test] Services_11"),
                            "1"=>array("value"=>"test_12","label"=>"[test] Services_12"),
                            "2"=>array("value"=>"test_13","label"=>"[test] Services_13"),
                            "3"=>array("value"=>"test_14","label"=>"[test] Services_14"),
                            )
                        )
        );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
foreach($a as $val)
  {
  $search =$val;
  $result = array_map(function ($value) use ($search) {
    //print_r($value);
    if(($key = array_search($search, $value['value'])) !== false) {
      unset($value['value'][$key]);
    }
   }, $b);
   print_r($result);
  }
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**OUT PUT:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => test_3
    [1] => test_4
)
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [label] => TEST
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_1
                            [label] => [test] Services_1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_2
                            [label] => [test] Services_2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_3
                            [label] => [test] Services_3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_4
                            [label] => [test] Services_4
                        )
                )
        )

    [test1] => Array
        (
            [label] => TEST
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_11
                            [label] => [test] Services_11
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_12
                            [label] => [test] Services_12
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_13
                            [label] => [test] Services_13
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_14
                            [label] => [test] Services_14
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And here i want only like this.

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [label] => TEST
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_1
                            [label] => [test] Services_1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_2
                            [label] => [test] Services_2
                        )
                )
        )

    [test1] => Array
        (
            [label] => TEST
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_11
                            [label] => [test] Services_11
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_12
                            [label] => [test] Services_12
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_13
                            [label] => [test] Services_13
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test_14
                            [label] => [test] Services_14
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Give me suggestion please.

Comment: do you have any code with yours tryouts to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes i try many code for that, but i can't get perfect result @rokas.

Comment: just use a foreach (probably two) then use an if in array, then unset

Comment: Hey Ghost thanks for that, I already use foreach then if and also unset, check my updated question, But i can't found my real result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($b as $j => $inner) {
    foreach ($inner['value'] as $k => $value) {
        if (in_array($value['value'], $a)) {      
            unset($b[$j]['value'][$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use unset on the top level of array (`$b`) with correct keys.

Comment: You must have copied it wrong, I just tested it and it's working, here's the full code:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a73bc763741de2524098c6cf032068ec6f4beccd